# Is calling stored procedures through the entity framework safe from SQL Injections?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, security, stored-procedures

I import the stored procedures to be used as functions in my ASP.NET MVC C# code. Are there any precautions I should take?

I'm using SQL Server 2017 and VS 2015.

Comment: Depends: does the stored procedure do any string concatenation to create sql statements to execute?

Comment: @HansKesting Don't believe so. What if it does?

Comment: When you concatenate user-supplied values into sql command strings, you *are* vulnerable. Whether you do it in source code or inside a stored procedure doesn't matter.

Comment: @HansKesting Thank you Hans